# Help me fix merged actions on export

Tags: animation, export, actions

I have a problem with blender, when I export my actions the poses are getting merged. I have tried to export "all actions" and then "NLA strips" , but I see the same error when I import the fbx to Unity. I tried creating a new basic model with 2 bones for a test and the same error happens there. Please help me fix this

Comment: What do you mean “the poses are merged“?

Comment: The poses were combined before. I exported a mesh with 2 different poses and each of them was a combination of both poses. I managed to fix it now by checking Force Start/End Keying in export options

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem, I needed to check *Force Start/End Keying* in export options under the *File Browser* side bar *Bake Animation*.